# Converting from int[] to int*

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C++ .DLL and C# application. In DLL I have a function like:

`namespace Sample
   {
    public ref class SampleClass
    {
     public: 
      int f(int arr[], int length);
    };
   }`

How can I call it from C# application? Problem is that in C++ I can use only `int*` argument and cannot declare `int[]`, and only `int[]` variable in c#.

I have tried to declare `int*[]` type in C# but it is impossible due to

> Cannot take address of a managed type

error. I have no idea how can I put an array into this function.

Upd:
trying to dllimport like

```
[DllImport("samplelib.fll", EntryPoint = "Sample.SampleClass.f")]
```

but that seems to be wrong.

Comment: Why would you even have that signature in C++? How do you know how many elements are in `arr`?

Comment: DllImport to...import that and signature simply int[]. See examples on MSDN.

Comment: @crashmstr `int f(int arr[])` is the same as `int f(int arr*)` in C++. The [] syntax is just there to confuse.

Comment: @juanchopanza but then the OP's argument about only being able to use `int*` (and **not** `int[]`) in C++ doesn't make sense.. He should be able to use both

Comment: @Default No, you can't declare an `int[]` (without a brace-encluses initializer list), but you can declare an `int*`. The two are the same in function parameter lists only.

Comment: @juanchopanza but in C# he wants to pass an integer array (i.e. `int[]`). I think the user is confusing C++ arrays and C# arrays a bit.

Comment: @crashmstr Right. And my first comment should be a hint to OP that there is no length information being passed with that signature in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this is what you want. Your example seems at bit incomplete ...

Let's say you have something like this in C/C++:

```
void TakesAnArray(int size, int array[]) {
   printf_s("[unmanaged]\n");
   for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
      printf("%d = %d\n", i, array[i]);
}
```

Then you want to call ist from C#, so you create a wrapper class.

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
   [DllImport("SomeLib.dll" )]
   public static extern void TakesAnArray(int size, [In, Out] int[] array);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. But i can't find the proper syntax for entry point. I`m trying Sample.SampleClass.f, but that doesn`t work.

Comment: @maniac98066 how to find entry point for C++ .DLL and use it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12885084/3908097

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
int ptrsize = arr.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));
IntPtr arrptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(ptrsize);
Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, arrptr, ptrsize);
NativeFunction(arr.Length, arrptr);
//after
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(arrptr);
```

Use the array as a pointer

```
void NativeFunction(int length, int* array) { /*...*/ }
```

Import(.\\ is executable path)

```
[DllImport(".\\MyLib.dll")]
static extern void NativeFunction(int length, IntPtr array);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the memory size of the array instead of the number of elements being passes into the C++ function?

Comment: @crashmstr yeah you are right fixed with length

Comment: -1: This code is already more complicated than using a proper P/Invoke signature, and doesn't handle releasing memory in all the exception cases where a proper signature would handle it for you.